# How to fetch data from API url if key is given in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I fetch data from a given URL if the key is also given in jQuery?

Let say the URL is: `/discover/movie?primary_release_date.gte=2014-09-15&primary_release_date.lte=2014-10-22`

The key is 4e5763a5269b4e3862f5a2eed7b9fb16
for me its showing

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: We need more information. There are lots of different ways that an API would use an authorisation key.

Comment: key in the sense you are meaning authorisation.

Comment: Let say i want to write function in jquery only then how you will approach @RoryMcCrossan you might describe atleast 2 ways that will be helpful for freshers like me.

Comment: I'd personally start by reading the docs of whichever API you're trying to call, and go from there. We have no idea what the API is, how its expecting that code to be passed or any of the detail we need to answer this

Comment: Again - it depends on how the key needs to be provided - does it need to be hashed? In a request parameter? In the header? Is it an `Basic` or `Authorization` header?
 Either way the jQuery docs tell you all you need to know about making the AJAX request: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Comment: If its an API key.... if get request try adding in querystring... if its a post try 2 possibilities one in querystring another in payload data.

Comment: @Hemakumar and then hash it in a header (lets just guess the key) and then provide it in the body of the post, and then a querystring....and then there are infinite other possibilities

Comment: Gosh google is too good sometimes. https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/discover

Comment: @Jamiec Your Google game is strong

Answer (score 3):

You need to add that key to the url as a search parameter.

```js
var apiKey = '4e5763a5269b4e3862f5a2eed7b9fb16'
var discoverUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?primary_release_date.gte=2014-09-15&primary_release_date.lte=2014-10-22'

$.get(discoverUrl + '&api_key=' + apiKey).then(console.log)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Next time, also mention what service/api you are using and don't let us play a guessing game

It's best is to read thiers [documentation](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/discover) and not to look at theirs [examples](https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api/discover) from where you took the url from

Comment: sure,I am very new to it so not aware .